# Christoffel symbols for the Poincaré ball model

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, hyperbolic-geometry, connections

The metric tensor $g_{ij}$ of the [Poincaré ball model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) is

$$ g_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{(1 - x_k x^k)^2} $$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and $x^k$ are the ambient Cartesian coordinates.

Hence the partial derivative of the metric tensor with respect to a coordinate $x^l$ is

$$ \partial_l g_{ij} = \partial_l \frac{\delta_{ij}}{(1 - x_k x^k)^2} = \delta_{ij} \partial_l (1 - x_k x^k)^{-2} = -2 \delta_{ij} (1 - x_k x^k)^{-3} \partial_l (1 - x_k x^k) = 2 \delta_{ij} (1 - x_k x^k)^{-3} (x_k \partial_l x^k + x^k \partial_l x_k) = 2 \delta_{ij} (1 - x_k x^k)^{-3} (x_k \delta_l^k + x^k \delta_{lk}) $$

In summary

$$ \partial_l g_{ij} = 2 \delta_{ij} (1 - x_k x^k)^{-3} (x_k \delta_l^k + x^k \delta_{lk}) = 4 \delta_{ij} (1 - x_k x^k)^{-3} x_l $$

The Christoffel symbols are defined in terms of the partial derivatives of the metric tensor as

$$ \Gamma^i_{jk} = \frac{1}{2} g^{il} (\partial_j g_{lk} + \partial_k g_{lj} - \partial_l g_{jk}) $$

Hence we substitute our expression for $ \partial_l g_{ij} $ with the right indices.

Is this correct? I have not been able to find an online source to verify that these are the correct Christoffel symbols for the Poincaré ball model.

Comment: Then it looks fine. For reference I get $\Gamma^i_{jk} = \frac{2}{(1 - x_\mu x^\mu)}[\delta^i_kx_{j} + \delta^i_jx_{k} - \delta_{jk}x^i]$ as the final result. The only thing I can see to criticize is the use of the notation $x_kx^k$ (which I also use above:) This usually means $g^{ij}x_ix_j$, i.e. the lower indices are lowered using the metric so it could potentially be confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference: check pages 160 and 161 of (the first edition?) do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry book. For $$g_{ij} = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{F^2}$$he proves that $$\Gamma_{ij}^k = -\delta_{jk}f_i-\delta_{ki}f_j+\delta_{ij}f_k,$$where $\log F = f$ and $f_i = \partial f/\partial x_i$. In this case, we have $F(x) = 1-\|x\|^2$, so that $$f(x) = \log F(x) = \log (1-\|x\|^2)\implies \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) = \frac{-2x_i}{1-\|x\|^2}.$$Putting everything together, one obtains $$\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{2(\delta_{jk}x_i + \delta_{ki}x_j-\delta_{ij}x_k)}{1-\|x\|^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't some of your indices be raised?

Comment: If you want to respect the index balance required by Einstein's convention, yes. The only reason I did not raise those indices was to keep the notation the same notation as do Carmo's (he does not use Einstein's convention), in case anyone reading actually wants to look at the book.